# Resume a webpage .read() with urlib

Tags: python, urllib

Here is my code :

```
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req=Request(url,headers=headers)
file=open(name,'wb')
file.write(urlopen(req).read())
file.close()
```

but when i get an exception and want to redownload the file i have to download from the begining ; and HTTPResponse don't have seek method . How can i resume my download ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [byte serving feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) of HTTP 1.0. Here you add the [range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header to your request. For example adding

```
Range: bytes=9500-
```

will download the file from the 9500th Byte. So you would do something like this in the end:

1. See how much bytes you have already downloaded.
2. Start the download from the first missing byte and append the output to the file.

**Notes:**

- The server need to support this technique (is not always the case).
- You can use [wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) which has already a support for continuing the download (see parameter `--continue`)